# Android - MutableSharedFlow failed to collect new values with multi subscribers

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-sharedflow

I want to create a shared view model for communication between MainActivity to fragments.
I decided to use share flow for managing events.

```
 private val _sharedChannel: MutableSharedFlow<SharedEvent> = MutableSharedFlow(
        replay = 0,extraBufferCapacity=0,onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.SUSPEND)
    val sharedChannel = _sharedChannel.asSharedFlow()
```

I don't need to cache the last event, not even when orientation changes.. so I set "replay = 0"

When I collect the events only in my main activity - everything works fine:

```
   lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {

        gamePlaySharedViewModel.sharedChannel.collect { event->
            SnappLog.log("GamePlayContainer-> sharedChannel EVENT: $event ")
            when(event){
                GamePlaySharedViewModel.SharedEvent.OnBackPress -> {
                    onBackPressed()
                }
                is GamePlaySharedViewModel.SharedEvent.BlockScreen -> {
                    blockScreen(event.isBlocked)
                }
                else -> {

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When adding a second subscriber to another fragment - both of the subscribers stop receiving events after the first one (the first event send successfully.. )
what can I do to subscribe for multi MutableSharedFlow?
I've tried to increase the number of "replay" and to change the "onBufferOverflow" - nothing seems to work..

Comment: How does the second subscriber looks like? Does it suspend when receiving an item?

Comment: The second subscriber looks the same, what do you mean "Does it suspend when receiving an item"?

Comment: As you have `BufferOverflow.SUSPEND` policy, a new item cam be emitted when the previous one has been consumed by **all** subscribers only. That means if one of you subscriber is slow in processing items, the producer suspends and waits for it.

Comment: Thanks @esentsov its seems that I had to cancel the coroutines job when one of my fragment was pausing

Comment: adsCollectorJob =   lifecycleScope.launch {
            adsManager.adsManagerChannel.collect { event ->
                SnappLog.log("QuestionFragment-> adsManagerChannel event: $event")
                when (event) {
                    is AdsManger.AdsManagerEvent.NotifySkipLevelRewarded -> {
                        notifySkipLevelRewarded()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        adsCollectorJob?.cancel()
    }